# Minimum number of substitutions to reach string: 01010101 ... 01 or 10101010 ... 10

Tags: java

Given a binary string, that is it contains only 0s and 1s (number of zeros equals the number of ones) We need to make this string a sequence of alternate characters by swapping some of the bits, our goal is to minimize the number swaps.

For example, for the string "00011011" the minimum number of swaps is 2, one way to do it is:

1) swap the bits : 00011011 --->> 00010111

2) swap the bits(after the first swap) : 00010111 --->> 01010101

Note that if we are given the string "00101011" we can turn it into an alternate string starting with 0 (that requires 3 swaps) and also into alternate string starting with 1 ( that requires one swap - the first and the last bits ).
So the minimum in this case is one swap.

The end goal is to return the minimum number of swaps for a given string of ones and zeros. What is the most efficient way to solve it?

Comment: First try writing some code of your own, no one here will write homework for you, if you have any problems after trying and doing your own research then come here with some code to show to us.As for String length  in Java  String has method length which returns number of characters in the string.

Comment: I would suggest to go step by step. First write code that determines the number of changes for both options. Then think how you can do that in a single pass. And unless I am mistaken log(n) is impossible - you have to check each bit in the existing string - there is no way to determine the final result without processing each entry at least once. But maybe I am wrong and somebody else has a better idea.

Comment: The teacher said that I can not use string methods only in charAt and length and in private methods.

Comment: I have been sitting for two hours on this exercise and can not find a good algorithm, at least you will give me a direction for a solution, I do not ask for a solution of the question

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It is a bit more complex since it works on all type of String not just bitstrings but based on the implementation you should be able to develop your own fitting solution. Here is an java implementation I found on [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java):

```
 public static int computeLevenshteinDistance(CharSequence lhs, CharSequence rhs) {      
    int[][] distance = new int[lhs.length() + 1][rhs.length() + 1];        

    for (int i = 0; i <= lhs.length(); i++)                                 
        distance[i][0] = i;                                                  
    for (int j = 1; j <= rhs.length(); j++)                                 
        distance[0][j] = j;                                                  

    for (int i = 1; i <= lhs.length(); i++)                                 
        for (int j = 1; j <= rhs.length(); j++)                             
            distance[i][j] = minimum(                                        
                    distance[i - 1][j] + 1,                                  
                    distance[i][j - 1] + 1,                                  
                    distance[i - 1][j - 1] + ((lhs.charAt(i - 1) == rhs.charAt(j - 1)) ? 0 : 1));

    return distance[lhs.length()][rhs.length()];                           
}
```

Comment: Hey, this talk is called alternating sequence

Comment: I don't understand you comment. What are you trying to tell / ask me?